# Web API 2 unit testing controller method not called?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make unit tests for my Web API 2.

I have a method that returns an IHttpActionResult

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Order))]]
public IHttpActionResult GetOrder(int orderId)
{
    return Ok(OrderHandeler.GetOrder(orderId);
}
```

Then i added this to my test project

```
var controller = new OrderController();
var order = controller.GetOrder(orderId) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Order>;
```

My problem is that order is always null, i even added logging to my GetOrder controller-method, but i don't get any logs either.

What am i doing wrong.

Comment: Everything written here seems to be right. Can you give more information ? What is `OrderHandeler` ? Do you mock your data access?  Does order exists with `orderId` ?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: first of all the code has a missing `)` there in the controller. But even so, i agree with @AramKocharyan - without the `OrderHandeler.GetOrder(orderId)` it is really hard to say what is going on and why. The typecast is correct.